# Compress MP3 files via an applet

Tags: java, applet, compression, mp3, client-side

I'm writing a recording applet. Is there a technique/API to compress the recorded MP3 on the client side using the applet before uploading it to the server?

Comment: You have access to all the `ZipOutputStream` and other you would normally. It all depends on how the MP3 comes in.

Comment: I'm quite sure an MP3 is already compressed enough that zipping it wouldn't bring any significant benefit.

Comment: Can you *encode* to MP3?  If you can, then I second the advice of @Renan, Zipping media files (audio, images, videos) typically does not reduce them one tiny bit, in fact, my last experiments doing that resulted in a zip file that was a **few bytes bigger** than the uncompressed file.  If you can encode to MP3, consider dropping the channels (e.g. stereo -> mono), the bit depth (16 bit to 8 bit samples) and sample rate (44.1 KHz - 11.025 KHz).  Making that series of changes would result in an AU or WAV **16** times smaller, though the saving will be less with an MP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, **zipping/compressing** media files **won't reduce its volume**, apparently i should set the recorded audio file to be efficient in terms of quality by choosing a lightweight audio format and setting some specific audio attributes and that would definitely help reducing the volume before the upload to the server.